# How to rotate a dynamic image 90 degrees in a jasper report?

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm generating PDF and Word documents using Jasper Reports (5.0.0).

In one of the documents I have to display an image from an URL. The image is generated dynamically before producing the report, but I don't have control over it (so I cannot rotate it at the source).

Is it possible to have Jasper rotate the image when it generates the document ?

Here's the template code for the image :

```
    <band height="706">
        <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
        <image rotation="Left" scaleImage="RetainShape" hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle" isUsingCache="false" isLazy="true" evaluationTime="Report">
            <reportElement key="" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="12" y="0" width="530" height="704" uuid="fc32abee-32e1-4b07-94f0-177eae9edcad">
                <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="local_mesure_unitx" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="local_mesure_unity" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
            </reportElement>
            <imageExpression><![CDATA[new java.net.URL($P{MAP_URL})]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
    </band>
```

As you can see the image URL is passed as a parameter to the report, and accessed over a java URL by Jasper. (In case there's no easy solution I plan to write a servlet that will fetch the image, and output it rotated, but I'd rather avoid that).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotating 90º In a Blob Image in JasperReports](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19788224/876298)

Comment: @AlexK I'm not asking how to rotate an image myself, I'm asking if jasper supports that out of the box.

Comment: This posts can help you: [Rotate column text by 60 degrees](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5230552/876298) & [Rotate text at any degree in JasperReports](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18374062/876298)

Comment: `I'm asking if jasper supports that out of the box` - No.

Answer (score 2):

No, I'm pretty sure you cannot.. The whole graphic situation is a heartbreak when it comes to Jasper Studio.. The best bet would be to alter the image before you put it in JasperStudio, as you are only allowed to re-size once its in there.